# Почему выходной файл js Vite добавляет в имя цифру 2?

Tags: laravel, vue3, vite

Получаю Build в свою указанную папку Front, но в имя JS-файла всегда добавляется 2:
формируются site.css и site2.js,
хотя в конфиге конкретно - хочу именно site.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
plugins: [
    vue({
        template: {
            transformAssetUrls: {
                base: null,
                includeAbsolute: false
            }
        }
    }),
    laravel({
        input: ['vue-resources/css/site.scss', 'vue-resources/site.js'],
        refresh:  [
            'vue-resources/css/**',
            'vue-resources/**',
            'vue-resources/components/**',
        ],
        buildDirectory: 'front',
    }),
],
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler',
    },
},
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
        output: {
            assetFileNames: 'site.css',
            entryFileNames: 'site.js',
        },
    },
    emptyDir: true,
},
});
```